# How do I reverse filter a visual?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to filter a visual so that all values are included except the ones I specify, I know I can filter normally by selecting all values and then de select the oens I dont want, but this is not feasible I need an easier way to exclude some values from the visual as a filter.

For example one table holds string values A,B,C,D,E,F and I want to show in the visual all values apart from A and B.

How can I do this so that I specify the A and B as opposed to electing all the other values I want, because they could be 10 000s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the NOT IN { List }

Something like:

```
FORMULA = CALCULATE( [MEASURE] , NOT (Table[Column] IN { "A", "B" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this dynamically with a slicer, then you'll need a separate parameter table with all the values of the column you're interested in filtering.

```
Measure = 
VAR SlicerSelection = VALUES ( Slicer[Column] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        < expression >,
        NOT ( Table[Column] IN SlicerSelection )
    )
```

Note: `Slicer` table should *not* have a relationship with `Table` in your model.